# For who's looking for plugin recommendation, should we suggest them to ask in Software Recomendation?

Tags: discussion

I just ask in the meta of Software Recommendation about the on-topic-ness of Wordpress' plugins, and their answer is yes. So should we suggest who are seeking for a recommendation of plugins to ask in there, and change the [FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

[Is asking about Wordpress's plugin on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2328/6389)

> Such requests are fully acceptable, as long as they stick to our other rules

Answer (score 8):

It's good that they are open to them. However there is also a concern if they are *good* for such questions (for WP stuff specifically, I trust any stack to be good for their general topic).

In my opinion it is easy to see this as trying to get rid of "unfitting" questions here, but we should also recommend *a best possible* alternative if we do.

I think we can start pointing people there on personal level, but I would hold on about codifying it in our docs before there is some solid history of it being a *good* destination for it.

Comment: Nothing more to add to it.

Comment: As we on [softwarerecs.se] expect/love to get recommendations from people that actually use the software, I hope there’s no *they* vs. *you*: we want and need the expertise from the WordPress community, for recommending WordPress on [\[cms\] questions](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms), and for recommending plugins (and other software that interacts with WP) on [\[wordpress\] questions](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress).

Comment: @unor to be clear my point of view is in no way confrontational or skeptical about your stack, it is more of a caution grown by _our_ issues with general deficiency of experts quantity in WP ecosystem. :) We might want to create a community ad to promote your stack here or something...

Comment: @Rarst: Yes, I understood it like that :) -- The community ad is a good idea. If we manage to come up with one, we’ll [submit](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3949/34147) it.

Comment: how do you define a "solid history"? Don't 50 questions of their [`wordpress tag`](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) count as a solid history?

Comment: @Ooker To be honest I was replying late in the evening so gave no thought what that might be practically yet. :)

Comment: so... what do you think now? Do you think it's good to suggest askers to go there? Also, your third comment is informative, consider to put it into your main answer.

Comment: I think a good history would be a good answer rate or QA ratio to the wordpress tag questions. It may also be beneficial to touch base with that exchanges mods and see if they believe it would be a good idea ( if beta have official mods ).

Answer (score 3):

So for reference, as of 4 August 2019, there are 173 questions for the [`wordpress` tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress?sort=MostVotes&edited=true) in Software Recommendations. In them:

- 118 questions with no answers (68%)
- 129 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers (75%)

According to @Howdy_McGee's definition of "good history" (a good history would be a good answer rate or QA ratio), it doesn't seem so.